# Why is this compiler output wrong when setjmp is involved?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Given this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
void foo(int x) {
  jmp_buf env;
  if (setjmp(env) == 0) {
    printf("%d\n", 23);
    longjmp(env, 1);
  } else {
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
}
```

The result should be that it prints 23 and then x and it should be all well defined.

But lets say the compiler has no knowledge that setjmp/longjmp are special functions and it generates the following code:

```
;function foo
;r0 : int x

foo:
    sub sp, sp, #sizeof(jmp_buf) ; reserve space for env
    push r0         ; save x for later
    add r0, sp, #4  ; load address of env
    call setjmp
    pop r1          ; restore SP, move x to r1 <<== corrupt after jongjmp
    cmp r0, #0      ; if (setjmp(env) == 0)
    bne 1f
    lea r0, "%d\n"  ; printf("%d\n", 23)
    mov r1, #23
    call printf
    mov r0, sp  ; load address of env
    mov r1, #1
    call longjmp
    b 2f
1:
    lea r0, "%d\n"      ; printf("%\dn", x), x already in r1
    call printf
2:
    add sp, sizeof(jmp_buf)
    ret
```

This will print 23 as expected but then it prints the retrun address of the longjmp call, i.e. the address of the 1 label.

The variable x is only temporarily stored on the stack to preserve it across the setjmp function call (r0, being an argument register, is caller saved). I think that is a perfectly valid thing for a compiler to do. But since setjmp returns twice this corrupts the variable while the C standard say it should not.

Comment: what do you mean by `the compiler has no knowledge that setjmp/longjmp are special functions` ?

Comment: Statement 1: *"I think that is a perfectly valid thing for a compiler to do."* Statement 2: *"But since setjmp returns twice this corrupts the variable while the C standard say it should not."* Statement 2 is correct that the C standard says it should not. Therefore statement 1 is false, it is ***not*** a perfectly valid thing for a compiler to do.

Comment: BTW: the statement *"lets say the compiler has no knowledge that setjmp/longjmp are special functions"* is also problematic. The `setjmp` and and `longjmp` functions are defined by the standard, and *are* special in the sense that they don't behave like other function calls. So if the compiler doesn't treat them as special, then the compiler must treat *all* function calls as if they were calls to `setjmp` or `longjmp`.

Comment: Which brings us to the heart of the matter. Where did you get that assembly code? Is that something that you just made up? Or is that the output of an actual compiler (that was given the exact C code shown in the question)?

Comment: It's what I get when I naively translate the C code by hand.

Comment: @alinsoar The compiler doesn't have an `if (ident=="setjmp") { // generate code special for setjmp calls } else { // generate code the normal way }`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Actually, the compiler probably does have that. Or some other special marker. The [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) says that setjmp should have a special marker `__attribute__((returns_twice))`

Comment: `setjmp` is a macro, not a function, although the macro could be implemented using a function, even a function with the same name. But a programmer is not allowed to bypass the macro, say by #undef, even if there happens to be a function of the same name. So there is an expectation that a given C implementation might need to do something non-standard.

Comment: @rici That helps and I would accept that as answer. A compiler that uses push/pop to save automatic variables across function calls like my example above would need setjmp as macro that saves all regs without function call that triggers those push/pop operations and the problem would go away.

Comment: @goswin: ok, i tried to expand that comment into an answer.

Comment: It's hard to believe in the existence of a C compiler that provides `setjmp()` in its headers and/or runtime library but doesn't know what its semantics are.

Comment: @user207421 On linux setjmp is provided by glibc as a plain function. Doesn't even have `__attribute__((returns_twice))`. The verry basic compiler I'm writing for fun so far has no special case for setjmp. So start believing. My compiler design simply isn't compatible with glibc's implementation of setjmp. Not every combination of compiler and libc can work.

Comment: "Not every combination of compiler and libc can work." This. An implementation can be viewed as consisting of a compiler, a linker and the standard library to be linked; the components are not independent of each other (and do not even need to be separate components).  `setjmp` is far from the only standard library facility which cannot be expressed in portable standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setjmp` is a macro, not a function, which is a recognition by the standard that on certain implementations it might require features not available to normal functions.

The standard explicitly allows the macro to simply expand to a function of the same name, for the case of implementations in which it can be implemented with a function using standard call semantics. However, if an application program attempts to bypass the macro, either with #undef or by using `(setjmp)(jmpbuf)`, it incurs Undefined Behaviour. This is the opposite of normal standard library functions which can also be implemented as macros as well as functions, but which can be accessed using the above techniques to avoid macro expansion.

Also, the fact that `setjmp` is specified to be a macro means that `&setbuf` is also undefined behaviour. In fact, the standard only allows a call to `setbuf` in two contexts:

1. As a complete expression statement, possibly with an explicit cast to `void`
2. In the condition of an `if` or loop statement, and only when the condition is

   - The `setjmp` call itself
   - The operator `!` with the `setjmp` call as its argument
   - A comparison between the `setjmp` call and an integer constant.

In other words, the value of the call to `setjmp` cannot be saved or participate in arithmetic, and no other computation can be performed inside the sequence points which surround the context of the call.

So the standards gives an implementation has lots of latitude for the implementation of `setjmp`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this compiler output wrong when setjmp is involved?

Because the compiler is not standard conforming. Because the side effects produced upon execution of the generated machine code do not correspond with the specification of the abstract machine as laid down in the C standard. Your code is an easy example, as `printf` produces a side effect. The compilers (only) job is generally to translate sentences from one language to another, so that side effects stay the same. If it fails to do that, well, it's broken.

The [C11 7.13.2.1p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.2.1p3) says:

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine have state, as of the time the longjmp function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and longjmp call are indeterminate.

`x` has automatic storage duration and is a local variable in a function and is not volatile, but it wasn't modified between the calls `setjmp` and `longjmp`. So, if `x` had some value before calling `longjmp`, it has to have the same value after calling `longjmp`.

A compiler that generates assembly code that does not conform to this specification is a not-conforming C compiler, or, in harsher words, it is not a C compiler at all.

There are compilers and architectures that just do not support `setjmp`/`longjmp` calls, and, well, it's fine. Such compilers explicitly state that they do not support `setjmp` and for example they can lack `setjmp.h` header, so that using it is impossible.

Comment: You have an example of an architecture which doesn't support setjmp? It's part of the C standard, so its only optional in a freestanding environment.

Comment: This is a non-answer. I already stated in the question that the resulting code behaves wrong. I'm looking for something more constructive than: It's wrong because it's wrong. Rici's comment on the question nailed it for me.